# Get the .html of a dynamically created element's descendant's child with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the .html() of `post-content-[[!+post.id]]` using `.on('click')`, however, the console keeps telling me there is no function for `.parent()` `.previous()`...

My HTML...

```
<div class="post-wrapper">
    <div class="post-header">
        <div class="post-avatar floatLeft">
            <a href=""><img class="miniCircle" src="[[!+post.photo]]"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="post-info floatLeft">
            <span class="in-line"><a href="">[[!+post.owner]]</a></span>
            <span class="in-line"><time class="timeago smallFont" datetime="[[!+post.date]]"></time></span>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="post-content">
        <div id="post-content-[[!+post.id]]" class="post-content i-content">[[!+post.content]]</div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-footer">
        [[!+post.links]]
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-star" style="display: inline-block" title="Like">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my script...

```
$('body').on('click', '.ui-icon', function (event) {
    console.log('content: ' + $(this).parent("div").previous("div").descendant(".i-content").html());
    // TypeError: $(...).parent(...).previous is not a function
});
```

How do I eliminate the "TypeError: $(...).parent(...).previous is not a function" and get the content that's in `post-content-[[!+post.id]]` without referring to it by ID?

Getting the html content of that div by ID only works on the first page load, then once my ajax updates the content, even if I use the new ID exactly, it will fail to target because the DOM has changed. But I know I can get the html content if I use relative targeting because I saw it in a tutorial, but that tutorial only exampled a single tier element set with a `<ul>` and its `<li>` children.

Comment: There's no `.descendant()` method in jQuery. Did you mean `.find()`?

Comment: And `.previous()` should be `.prev()`. Where are you getting these nonexisting function names from?

Comment: Also, there is no .previous() methon in jQuery. Did you mean .prev()?

Comment: You need the manual!  https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Comment: Well, I'm just learning so please forgive my ignorance. It does work with the right functions named. I typed .previous into my IDE and it colored as a function keyword so I just thought I broke something else. Oops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be [`.prev([selector])`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) and [`.children([selector])`](https://api.jquery.com/children/), this will, however, only traverse one line down.

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .children() method allows us to search through the children of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements. The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well. Note also that like most jQuery methods, .children() does not return text nodes; to get all children including text and comment nodes, use .contents().

Alternatively, you could try referencing the child via [CSS ancestry](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/descendant-selector-css-selector/).

[Here](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) is a nice reference in the documentation, you may find some alternative options that I've not listed. **`previous()` should definitely be `prev()`, though! As to answer the question.**

Here is a reference of an implementation I did a long time ago when I was learning jQuery (I'm still no expert, I do SuiteScript/Automation/Business Logic):

```
    $(".title").click(function(){
    var height = $(this).parent().children(".content").children("p").height();
    if($(this).parent().children(".content").height() == 0){
        height = height.toString() + 'px';

        /* Reset styling of all posts */
        $(".title").css("color","black");
        $(".content").css({"height": "0px", "color": "#5a5858"});

        /* Set this post's styling */
        $(this).css('color','white');
        $(this).parent().children(".content").css({'height': height, 'color':'white'});
    /* On unclick */    
    } else {
        $(this).css('color', 'black');
        $(this).parent().children(".content").css({'height': '0px', 'color':'#5a5858'});
    }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! I have been referencing the documentation usually, but this time I assumed that those were functions because of code coloring in my IDE. I should have went back to the documentation first.

Answer (score 2):

.previous() doesn´t exists, use prev(), and .descendant() neither, you can use .children() or find()

https://api.jquery.com/prev/

https://api.jquery.com/children/

https://api.jquery.com/find/

, its telling you  is not a function because it doesnt really exists, not because any bug in you code.

Comment: Thank you for the links and answering, but I gave this one to @specrte-d for including the documentation quotes, and a more complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try
    console.log('content: ' + $(this).parent().prev().children().html());

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I gave this one to @specrte-d for including the documentation quotes, and a more complete answer.